# how to make container unsticky after some point

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Whenever the pink container touches the bottom of green container I want to make it unsticky. Is it possible? I tried but couldn't achieve it.

here's the code

also codepen link : [Click Here](https://codepen.io/SharmaKiran/pen/qBywwZd)

```css
.container1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

.container3 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container3">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Perhaps a drawing would help.